# joining two or multiple PCollection *without* key in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

Suppose 
   PCollection p1 has {1,2,3}
   PCollection p2 has {A,B,C}

I would like to generate PCollection which has pairs from p1 and p2 like
{A,1}, {B,2}, {C,3}

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
K

Comment: Any combination of 1:1 mapping is fine. like {A,3} {B,1} {C,2} is also ok.

Comment: Can you tell more about what you're trying to achieve using this? It's a somewhat odd operation so I suspect there might be a better way to achieve your actual end goal.

Comment: There is no specific relation between P1 and P2. It's like the list of guys and the list of girls. I just need the list of 1:1 mapping.

Comment: But what do you do with the mapping afterwards? Also, how many are there: would they fit in memory? And what would you want to do if the collections have different sizes, or if one or both are unbounded (streaming)?

Comment: thx. jkff. p1 will the same or larger than p2. so, some elements in p2 may not have matching. the size of collection will may not fit in memory.  they are bounded. The result of the mapping will be used for some other service, which is not dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd recommend using a [stateful ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html) to assign sequential numbers 1, 2, ... to elements of each `PCollection`, and then use a `CoGroupByKey` to perform a join. That means each `PCollection` will be sequentially processed using 1 worker, but I currently can't think of a way to implement this particular operation more efficiently.